# How do you compute the derivatives of these summation problems.

Tags: derivatives, summation

1. $\frac d {d I_{j}} (B I)$
2. $\frac d {d I_{j}} (g I_{j-1})$

Where g, B, are constants and $I$=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\ I_{k}$

j=2...b,

My initial thought would be that the answers are:

1. $j B$
2. $y(j-1)$

But I'm really not sure .. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here we consider variables $I_1,\ldots,I_k$. In case of more than one variable we rather use the *[partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative)* notation $\frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}$ instead of $\frac{d}{d I_j}$.

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}I_k=
> \begin{cases}
> I_j\qquad&k=j\\
> 0\qquad&\text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

we obtain due to linearity of the derivative operator for $n\geq 1$:

> \begin{align*}
> &\frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}(BI)
> =\frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}\left(B\sum_{k=1}^nI_k\right)=B\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}I_k=BI_j&\qquad1\leq j\leq n\\
> &\frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}(gI_{j-1})
> =g\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial I_j}(I_{j-1})=g\cdot 0=0&\qquad2 \leq j\leq n
> \end{align*}